# rmdir dir gives error 'Not a directory'

Tags: command-line, directory

I have what looks to be a directory directory `dir2`, I once moved it from another directory `dir1` to back it up and created a new `dir1`.

Now I suddenly saw it again, realized I didn't need it and did `rm -r -f dir2`, and found out that my new `dir1` is also empty.

I got my files back (is was a code repository, so just some changes lost - bummer), but I still want to remove this redundant link or whatever `dir2` is.

When I tried `rmdir` (before I realized I deleted everything) I got an error `Not a directory`. What is it and how do I remove it? Using bash on OSX terminal.

**Update:** Per suggestions below:

`ls -ld dir2` outputs `drwxr-xr-x. 19 asaf users 4096 Mar  8 13:09 dir2/`

`file dir2/` outputs `dir2/: directory`

`file dir2` outputs `dir2: symbolic link to ...'`

Comment: share the output of ls -l dir2 ,

Comment: You can also use `file dir2` to get more information on it. - From your description is might be a symlink. Maybe it already was a symlink in the beginning and you simply moved that symlink, but the actual files live somewhere else. - But to be sure we need the output of `ls -l dir2` or `file dir2`.

Comment: @GauravPundir Make that `ls -ld dir2` (in case it is in fact a directory)

Comment: @michas If it was a symlink, `rm -r -f dir2` wouldn't have deleted anything but the symlink. (It's possible that the actual command was `rm -r -f dir2/`, which would have descended into the directory, or that the symlink was deleted and sprite's changes are still in whatever location the symlink pointed to.)

Comment: Updated question with output of both.

Comment: @sprite As i thought, its a symlink. use unlink command `unlink dir2`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's impossible to know what happened given that the evidence is now deleted. Your descriptions of the symptoms is consistent with `dir2` being a [symbolic link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link) to a directory. A symbolic link is a sort of special file that says “the real file is actually over there”. The symbolic link itself isn't a directory, so `rmdir` can't do anything with it. But accesses to the content of the symbolic link (files in the directory for a symbolic link pointing to a directory, file contents for a symbolic link pointing to a regular file) go to the target of the link transparently, so you wouldn't have noticed anything when using `cd dir2` or when editing files in the directory.

If this is the case (which is plausible, but not at all certain!), then the command `rm -r -f dir2` only deleted the symbolic link, and the directory containing your changes still exists… somewhere. Since you've deleted the link, it might be difficult to find where, but you can try looking for the file names that you know were in that directory with the [`locate`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/locate.1.html) command or with an equivalent GUI (Spotlight?).

In the future, run

```
ls -ld dir2
```

That would tell you what kind of file `dir2` is. If the line begins with `d`, it's a directory. If the line begins with `l`, it's a symbolic link, and the output indicates where it points to (the part after `->`).

Comment: Updated question with output.

Comment: @sprite I thought you'd deleted `dir2`? Anyway the output from `ls` and `file` shows that it is indeed now a symbolic link to a directory.

Answer (score 3):

If you run `ls -ld dir2` it should tell us a lot about the situation.

It could be a symlink, or an odd type of file. I know at this point we're assuming it is a directory, but there are other options. It may even be a lost automount share.

Also try running `file dir2`. If it is anything but a true directory, you're likely going to to see an error with `rmdir`.

Comment: Updated question with output.